# Sqlalchemy join multiple collection_class=list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to collect objects from two related tables into one "main" record. Both relations are. many-to-one (many Metric/Posts to a single Entity), and there might not be Posts, thus the query in the end is an outerjoin.

It's all mapped imperatively and looking as follow

Python classes

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Metric:
    entity_id: str
    name: str
    value: float


@dataclass
class Post:
    post_id: str
    entity_id: str
    content: str


@dataclass
class Entity:
    entity_id: str
    name: str
    metrics: list[Metric] = field(default_factory=list)
    posts: list[Post] = field(default_factory=list)
```

and the mapping

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry, relationship
from sqlalchemy.types import Float, String

metadata = MetaData()
entity = Table(
    "entity",
    metadata,
    Column("entity_id", String(), primary_key=True),
    Column("name", String(), nullable=False),
)

metric = Table(
    "metric",
    metadata,
    Column("entity_id", String(), ForeignKey("entity.entity_id"), ondelete="CASCADE", primary_key=True),
    Column("name", String(), primary_key=True),
    Column("value", Float(), nullable=False),
)

post = Table(
    "post",
    metadata,
    Column("entity_id", String(), ForeignKey("entity.entity_id"), ondelete="CASCADE", primary_key=True),
    Column("post_id", String(), primary_key=True),
    Column("content", String(), nullable=False),
)


mapper_registry = registry()
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Entity,
    entity,
    properties={
        "posts": relationship(
            Post,
            cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-oprhan",
            backref="entity",
            collection_class=list,
        ),
        "metrics": relationship(
            Metric,
            cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-oprhan",
            backref="entity",
            collection_class=list,
        )
    }
)
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Post,
    post,
)
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Metric,
    metric,
)
```

The query that I'm trying to make creates pretty much a cartesian product, what is not what I intend to get out of it. It works, but it is unnecessary slow to get the answer and it's definitely not scalable..

query:

```py
select(Entity, Metric, Post)
.join(Metric,
    Metric.entity_id == Entity.entity_id,
).outerjoin(Post,
    Post.entity_id == Entity.entity_id
).
options(
    contains_eager(Entity.posts),
    contains_eager(Entity.metrics),
)
```

Any way I could do it a non-cartesian product query like, that i still using domain objects instead of having to execute a few manual queries and collect the objects myself?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cartesian product"?

Comment: It's not a pure cartesian product as there is an ON clause specified, but the generated query produces end row like every row from Metric with every row from Post with every row from Entity... and the number of results grows exponentially

Comment: Could you please specify which query was generated and which query you require?